# Changing a subarray in document will not rerender with proper order

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using jQuery UI sortable to update the order of an array stored in a container document. When the sort fires the "stop" method, it rebuilds the array and orders it based on the new DOM layout. It all works fine and the updated document reflects the proper order. HOWEVER, the dom reloads and the order is back to what it was.

When I physically refresh the page it actually shows the proper order. It's just that on-the-fly changing of the array won't just re-render itself properly.

Interestingly enough, this problem has only cropped up in 0.9.4, so it may be a bug with meteor, just not sure if there was a change that would affect what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'd provide code examples if needed, but since the code itself seems to be working properly and the each not updating to reflect the order, i'm not sure it'll help at all.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I've put together a standalone demo of the problem, listed out in my comment below:

Ok, here's a crazy example of the issue:

demo: [app-9ryym2m2.meteorpad.com](http://app-9ryym2m2.meteorpad.com/)

source: [meteorpad.com/pad/uQ42DRH95JcHtKnb9](http://meteorpad.com/pad/uQ42DRH95JcHtKnb9)

Try doing some sorting of items to see part1 of the issue. Next, after sorting, try hitting the togglers a few times, especially within the list of items you sorted. That's part2 of the issue. Now, if you refresh the page, everything gets caught up. Wat.

**Double Update**

Thanks to aldeed over at Github, I've got a solution: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2944

By changing my sub-document reference key from 'id' to '_id', Blaze seems to pick up on the changes to sorting no problem!

Comment: Based on more exploring, it seems that Meteor is only doing a full re-render when the lists are of differing sizes before and after the call to update. If I just re-order the array and save it as the new value, I get issues. Continuing to dig...

Comment: Explorations continue. Instead of modifying the order of the array, I update only the rank value for each item in the array and use a helper to do the sorting manually. Same problem, except it opens up some other interesting bugs when I actually start to modify the documents when they are already sorted. I'm going to try making a simplified example that I can share.

Comment: Ok, here's a crazy example of the issue:

http://app-9ryym2m2.meteorpad.com/

http://meteorpad.com/pad/uQ42DRH95JcHtKnb9

Try doing some sorting of items to see part1 of the issue. Next, after sorting, try hitting the togglers a few times, especially within the list of items you sorted. That's part2 of the issue. Now, if you refresh the page, everything gets caught up. Wat.

Comment: The url for demo above doesn't work for me.

Comment: @rdickert try the meteorpad link instead. Turns out meteorpad shuts down the server if I'm not logged in. Or something like that!

Comment: @irrationalistic Thank you for tracking down the root of this problem and saving me a lot of time! :) I had the same issue with RubaXa/Sortable, so I will just leave this comment here in case someone else will search for it.

Answer (score 0):

I confess that I haven't dug into your code, but the way it is updating indicates that you are picking up the previous state rather than the updated state. Wherever you drag, the final state reflects the last place you dragged to (even though it was probably in the wrong place when you started). Perhaps an order-of-execution/async bug?

Have you seen the drag and drop demo that was put together for blaze by Avital Oliver (Meteor core dev) when the blaze rendering engine came out? You can watch [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISNEhPG0wnA) and check out [the repo](https://github.com/avital/drag-and-drop). If you try the demo and it fails on the current version of Meteor, you can submit an issue there and get some support from the pros :)

Comment: Thanks @rdickert! It's slightly different because those demos are at the document level while my system is a complicated relationship from a subarray of document ids to a separate collection. If you really mess with the demo, you can see how strange it gets!

Comment: Yeah, played with it some more the behavior is complex and confusing! I still think that a solution like Avi's could be the way to go, though. It might require a little restructuring, but it would be easier to reason about what's happening. You are basically performing a merge on your collections in the template (using `#with getPlayer`). The easiest solution would be to denormalize your data and save player data directly on the Teams collection, but if you prefer not to, you could merge in your helper (before iterating over the players), and the each *should* correctly manage the ordering.

Comment: On the toggle functionality, I would avoid storing that on the dom and instead update directly to the collection (and let blaze toggle any dom elements via the template). I'm not sure what's happening here, but my working hypothesis would be that due to the `with`, blaze is missing context to be able to manage elements. All of this is not solving your problem directly, though. If you think this is actually a bug in blaze, you should report it, and people who know a lot more than I do will have a look!

Comment: Thanks @rdickert! I'll give this a shot and let you know what I come up with.